# Allegro 5 assertion fail

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, allegro, allegro5

I am trying to load a bitmap with allegro 5.0.10

```
ALLEGRO_PATH *path = al_get_standard_path(ALLEGRO_RESOURCES_PATH);
al_set_path_filename(path, "Bitmap.bmp");

al_init_image_addon();
ALLEGRO_BITMAP *bmp = al_load_bitmap(al_path_cstr(path, '/'));
if (!bmp) {
    fprintf(stderr, "No Background.bmp in this directory...");
    return -2;
}

al_draw_bitmap(bmp, 0, 0, 0);
```

Once i tried to run the program in debug mode, i get this error:

```
Assertion failed!

Program: c:\allegro\bin\allegro-5.0.10-monolith-md-debug.dll
File: allegro-git\src\system.c
Line: 336

Expression: active_sysdrv

...
```

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize allegro by calling `al_init()`. Very few Allegro functions can be called before doing that.

Comment: I did not show the full code, but I did the necessary stuff already

Comment: @junyi00, if you had called `al_init()` you wouldn't get that error.

Answer (score 0):

@junyi00, you need to make sure that you call `al_init()` before trying to load any resources. In your code above, make sure `al_init()` is already called before calling `al_get_standard_path(ALLEGRO_RESOURCES_PATH)`, `al_set_path_filename(path, "Bitmap.bmp")`, `al_load_bitmap(al_path_cstr(path, '/'))` and basically all the Allegro functions from there. No other Allegro functions can be called before this function except one or two. See http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/en/man3/al_init.3alleg5.html and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man3/al_install_system.3alleg5.html These are links to the al_init() and al_install_system() Allegro function manual pages